# training haar and lbp classifiers in openCV

Tags: opencv

I have downloaded openCV 2.4.4 in a windows executable form. It had all the libraries that are needed pre built. 
Now i am creating an object detection program that requires creating a haar or lbp classifier. I have found that opencv_traoncascade is now the preferred utility and the others are deprecated. The problem is that i am not able to find that utility in opencv2.4.4.exe which i downloaded. There is a folder traincascade but all it has are some hpp files.
Is there a way i can get it, i dont want to checkout the trunk and build it using cmake.
Also some reference to good tutorials explaining thus new utility will be helpful.

Comment: [This](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) is the tutorial that helped me when I was training haar classifiers with openCV 2.0. I remember that to use the new utilies you just change the executable name in the commands that are described in the tutorial.

Comment: Note that the training time is long (can be two-three weeks on a single CPU). Because of this it is recommended that you compile the source by yourself with TBB enabled in order to use all your CPUs and shorten running time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (as my exp.) two ways to do you want: use CMake or create your project and copy code you're need  from opencv (this is not good idea:)).

I dont understand what you mean:

> i dont want to checkout the trunk and build it using cmake

if you already

> downloaded openCV 2.4.4 in a windows executable form

you have all to use CMake: open cmake, set source code: "...\opencv" and binary path (may be the same). Next - press configure, next - enable option "build examples", press configure second time, press generate... 
It's all. Now open project opencv, find traincascade subproject and build it:)

Answer (score 0):

There are some files in the archive. E.g. cascadeclassifier.cpp (CPU and GPU in the samples folder and the source in opencv/modules) and traincascade.cpp.
There is also [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) guide. I've heard that training is a bit difficult. If you come with a complete answer, feel free to share it.